# How do you compile C#?

Tags: c#, compilation

So, I was wondering how to compile C#. I have Windows 7 Enterprise. Is there a built-in program or do I have do download one?

If I have to download one, what do you recommend?

I have Googled this, and it told me about "csc.exe" but I can't find this.

Comment: I'd recommend VisualStudio 2010, I'm assuming this is a work PC since you have W7 Enterprise, so I'd see if your workplace has a VS2010 license too.  You can use command line tools, of course, but the VS2010 suite is a great productivity booster.

Comment: Start by installing Visual Studio Express edition 2010

Comment: try it >where csc at command prompt

Answer (score 14):

For any real development, an IDE is preferable. Microsoft offers the [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) edition for free, which has everything you need to get started with C#.

However, you can compile using just the command line compiler (csc.exe), which is included with the framework.

It should be located in the .NET installation dir; for instance on my machine for .NET 4, 64 bit version, I have a csc.exe in:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

Answer (score 9):

Your choices are:

1. [csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx) (the command line compiler), which is in c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\
2. Install Visual Studio Express, the free edition of VS, for [Windows/Console Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express), [Web Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express), or [Windows Phone Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/windows-phone-developer-tools)
3. [Purchase a license for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/buy) or get an [MSDN subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/aa718661.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Use the command line compiler `csc`

```
C:\>csc file.cs
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Visual Studio Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) which is a full featured free IDE from Microsoft that will compile C#.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're starting fresh, why not use an IDE that does it for you?

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express

Answer (score 1):

You can find the command-line compiler, `csc.exe`, in `\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vX.Y`.

However, you will probably want to use Visual Studio, Microsoft's world-class IDE.
You can download the [free version](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express).

Answer (score 0):

For literally *compiling* C#: [Native Image Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

Otherwise get Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio will be the easiest way. There are free editions available - see http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) to compile it once you have it installed. Once you have it installed you can go to Visual Studio Command Prompt and Use C# compiler csc.exe to compile it.

Look here for more information [Command-Line Building](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the framework installed (2.0, minimum).  Then follow this *old* article for a simple how-to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563(v=vs.80).aspx

NOTE: Microsoft IDEs like VS can do this for you also.

Comment: Windows 7 comes with all versions of the .NET Framework up to 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do this by default with Windows 7 Enterprise.  At very least you are likely going need visual studio.

You can get Visual C# here for free: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express

Answer (score 0):

I would advice [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), the express edition is for free, you can find more information on the microsoft site over [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express).

Answer (score 0):

I started using SharpDevelop as a portable text editor that understood ASPX files out-of-the-box (vs. Sublime, etc.), but I've build a couple of small (<10K lines) utilities using just that and CSC now.  A portable copy of SharpDevelop is especially handy when you don't have the administrative permissions (or time) to install full Microsoft Visual Studio in an environment.

Download the "XCopyable" edition to get the portable edition of SharpDevelop from here: 
http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/Default.aspx#SharpDevelop5x

Answer (score -1):

Also consider the option of using Mono & MonoDevelop available for Mac, Linux and Windows. Not a bad choice for a serious beginner.